# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SUPABASE_URL')

Tags: supabase, nuxt3, .env

Im trying to work with Supabase but I got a error I cant seem to fix..

I have a supabaseClient.js with the following code:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

export default supabase
```

I have a ".env" file in my root folder with:
SUPABASE_URL=https://xxxx
SUPABASE_KEY=xxxxxxxxx

I also have the dotenv npm package installed, Followed a couple of guides that do exactly this, but when I try to console.log(supabase) I get the "console.log" data in my terminal, but my application crashes with the saying:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SUPABASE_URL')

Do anyone know PLEASE how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use [Nuxt Supabase module](https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/), it will handle client creation for you. You just provide `.env` file and call `useSupabaseClient` in your code.

The error you're getting is probably because `process.env` is not available in Nuxt's client side. If you insist on creating your Supabase client manualy, you'll have to use [runtime config](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config) to provide environment variables or handle your database connection [on server side](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was confusing myself, the answer you provided works great:)